# how to create a hyperlink in listview subitem using winapi

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to add a hyperlink in listview subitem (that appears only in detail view), that woulde be treated as normal hyperlink (with changing mouse coursor, changing font color after link being clicked and etc.). How can I do this using WinAPI?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I know how to do this using custom drawn subitems, managing mouse moves, text drawing and other things. I'm looking for simplier solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A standard ListView control simply does not natively support hyperlinks, so you must implement them manually.  Using owner-drawing, hit testing, etc is typically the better way to accomplish that.  The only other option I know of would be to create a separate [SysLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760704%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or other hyperlinked control for each list item, make them children of the ListView, and reposition them as needed whenever the ListView scrolls.  That tends to be more hassle than using owner-drawing.